# AccessDeniedError [SequelizeAccessDeniedError]: Login failed for user ''

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My node.js server keeps failing the sequelize connection with the following error.

```js
AccessDeniedError [SequelizeAccessDeniedError]: Login failed for user 'tester'.
    at ConnectionManager.connect (C:\tools\MyApp\Server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:115:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ConnectionManager._connect (C:\tools\MyApp\Server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:220:24)
    at async C:\tools\MyApp\Server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:174:32 {
  parent: ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'tester'.
      at Login7TokenHandler.onErrorMessage (C:\tools\MyApp\Server\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\handler.js:245:19)
      at Readable.<anonymous> (C:\tools\MyApp\Server\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:26:33)
      at Readable.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
      at next (node:internal/streams/from:98:31)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    code: 'ELOGIN',
    isTransient: undefined
  },
  original: ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'tester'.
      at Login7TokenHandler.onErrorMessage (C:\tools\MyApp\Server\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\handler.js:245:19)
      at Readable.<anonymous> (C:\tools\MyApp\Server\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:26:33)
      at Readable.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
      at next (node:internal/streams/from:98:31)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    code: 'ELOGIN',
    isTransient: undefined
  }
}
```

This is a config file with connection strings:

```js
{
        "server": server,
        "database": database,
        "instance": "",
        "user": "tester",
        "password": "12345"
}
```

This is my code for sequelize connection:

```js
const config = require("../../config.json");
var SQL_Connection = config.SQL_Connection;

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  SQL_Connection.database,
  SQL_Connection.user,
  SQL_Connection.password,
  {
    dialect: "mssql",
    host: SQL_Connection.server,
    logging: false,
    dialectOptions: {
      requestTimeout: 30000,
      connectionTimeout: 30000,
    },
    pool: {
      max: 50,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000,
    },
  }
);
```

I have a test environment on stage with the same configuration and it works fine. But this production is erroring out.. I have no idea.

I did user mapping in ssms for the user, "tester". But no luck..

Please advise.